# about the Divergent Sum

Tags: calculus

I try to sum the following series but Matemathica  say is Divergent but I get the following result:
$$\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{-k^{10}+5 \pi ^2 k^8+8 \pi ^4 k^6+120 \pi ^6 k^4+57 \pi ^8 k^2+3 \pi ^{10}}{2 \pi ^6 (\pi -k)^5 (k+\pi )^5}=-2 \pi ^2+6 \pi ^4 \cot ^5\left(\pi ^2\right)-6 \pi ^2 \cot ^4\left(\pi ^2\right)+10 \pi ^4 \cot ^3\left(\pi ^2\right)+\cot ^3\left(\pi ^2\right)-8 \pi ^2 \cot ^2\left(\pi ^2\right)+4 \pi ^4 \cot \left(\pi ^2\right)+\cot \left(\pi ^2\right)$$
Following the comments of @Lulu
I gave the following series
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{16 \pi ^{10} k \coth (\pi  k)}{\left(k^4-\pi ^4\right)^4}-\frac{80 \pi ^2 k^9 \coth (\pi  k)}{\left(k^4-\pi ^4\right)^4}-\frac{160 \pi ^6 k^5 \coth (\pi  k)}{\left(k^4-\pi ^4\right)^4}\right)=\pi ^3 \cot ^3\left(\pi ^2\right)+\frac{2}{3} \pi ^3 \cot \left(\pi ^2\right)-\pi ^3 \coth ^3\left(\pi ^2\right)+\frac{2}{3} \pi ^3 \coth \left(\pi ^2\right)-\pi ^3 \cot ^4\left(\pi ^2\right) \coth \left(\pi ^2\right)-\pi ^3 \cot ^3\left(\pi ^2\right) \coth ^2\left(\pi ^2\right)-\pi ^3 \cot ^2\left(\pi ^2\right) \coth ^3\left(\pi ^2\right)-\frac{1}{3} \pi ^3 \cot ^2\left(\pi ^2\right) \coth \left(\pi ^2\right)+\frac{1}{3} \pi ^3 \cot \left(\pi ^2\right) \coth ^2\left(\pi ^2\right)-\pi ^3 \cot \left(\pi ^2\right) \coth \left(\pi ^2\right)$$ the limit 
$$\underset{k\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(-\frac{16 \pi ^{10} k \coth (\pi  k)}{\left(k^4-\pi ^4\right)^4}-\frac{80 \pi ^2 k^9 \coth (\pi  k)}{\left(k^4-\pi ^4\right)^4}-\frac{160 \pi ^6 k^5 \coth (\pi  k)}{\left(k^4-\pi ^4\right)^4}\right)$$ gives 0

Comment: How did you get that result?

Answer (score 2):

Dividing numerator and denominator by $k^{10}$ and letting $k$ go to $\infty$ we get $-1$ in the numerator and $-2\pi^6$ in the denominator.  Thus the terms do not tend to $0$ in the limit, so the sum diverges.

Comment: Yes @Lulu is is correct but if you sum a fews term you will see that converge for examples $$\sum _{k=-100}^{100} \frac{-k^{10}+5 \pi ^2 k^8+8 \pi ^4 k^6+120 \pi ^6 k^4+57 \pi ^8 k^2+3 \pi ^{10}}{2 \pi ^6 (\pi -k)^5 (k+\pi )^5}$$ it is aproximate 32052.3

Comment: I don't get your point.  Of course the finite sums converge, all finite sums converge.

Comment: increase the term and you get te same result ,the condition that the general term tend to zero it is not sufficient condition

Comment: It is a necessary condition for convergence.  Note that $\frac 1{2\pi^6}\approx .0005$ so of course the partial sums are close (for a while).  You need about $2000$ terms to change the partial  sum by $1$.